# Make segment of code in c# thread un-interruptible

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using a c# thread in which I want to take a snapshot of 28 dictionaries (stored in an array for easy access) that are being populated by event handler methods, in the thread I'm looping over the array of dictionaries and storing the snapshots using ToList() method in another array of Lists, so that I can do some work in the thread afterwards even though the collections keep changing in real-time. The problem is that I want the snapshots of all dictionaries to be as close in time as possible, so I don't want my thread to be interrupted while I'm looping over the array. The code looks something like this:

```
public void ThreadProc_Scoring()
{
  List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>, double>>[] SnapBOUGHT = new List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>, double>>[27];
  List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>, double>>[] SnapSOLD = new List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>, double>>[27];

  int index;
  int NormIdx;
  DateTime actual = new DateTime();
  double score = 0;
  double totAScore = 0;
  double totBScore = 0;
  double AskNormalization = 1;
  double BidNormalization = 1;

  while (true)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(15000);

    //Get a snapshot of BOUGHT/SOLD collections
    //Enter un-interruptible section
    foreach (var symbol in MySymbols)
    {
      index = symbol.Value;
      SnapBOUGHT[index] = BOUGHT[index].ToList();
      SnapSOLD[index] = SOLD[index].ToList();
    }

    //Exit un-interruptible section

    //Do some work on Snapshots
  }
```

If you have any other suggestions on how to approach the situation, I'd be grateful for the help. Thank you!

Comment: `ThreadInterruptedException` is an Exception that gets thrown by `Thread.Sleep`

just place a **try - catch block** over `Thread.Sleep` and see where it brings you. You will have to think about what you want to do when the sleeping is interrupted or isnt interrupted. The Thread doesnt end when that is thrown. It's just there to wake up sleeping threads, mostly so that they can terminate cooperatively by checking for a value where you have `while(true)`

Comment: The requirement is simply wrong. You don't need code that doesn't get interrupted by other threads - what does that even mean on multi-core CPUs? Freeze the entire server? And since you seem to be dealing with stock exchange data, not needed at all. Not even for algorithmic trading

Comment: If you want to improve performance, eliminate `ToList()`. What does `BOUGHT[index]` contain, and why does it need `ToList()`? Why use a `List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>, double>>[] ` instead of proper classes, structs etc? After all, you're just storing timestamped values. You don't need a `KeyValuePair`. A simple class or struct with a `DateTime` and a `double` field would be better

Comment: If you want to reduce latency *don't* take snapshots of the entire history each time (I'd say if you poll every 15 sec, worrying about latency is a bit premature). Retrieve only *new* prices and post them to workers for processing, eg to ActionBlocks that can process just the new data if needed, or work over the entire set otherwise. Calculating min, max, average, opening, closing doesn't need the entire snapshot every time. Finding the median value does.

Comment: `I can do some work in the thread afterwards even though the collections keep changing in real-time.` I don't understand how your code works without locking. You can't `ToList` a Dictionary that is changing in another thread. `Dictionary` isn't thread-safe. Have you considered `ImmutableDictionary` instead?

Comment: This looks like a case of [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem with X (stock data processing takes too long), and assume Y is the solution (somehow freezing the rest of the OS, whatever that could mean in a multicore machine). When that doesn't work, you asked about Y, not X. What is *X*? And what does your code really do that prevents it from doing its job?

Comment: What is the type of the `BOUGHT` and `SOLD` variables?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your enthusiasm but I wouldn't loop over entire collections if I didn't need all the data, I need historical transactions for scoring purpuses, it's not about calculating min, max etc. values. I'm just asking if I can make my thread uninterruptible while collecting the snapshots right after that I don't care if it gets interrupted.

Comment: Why are you looping multiple times then? `ToList()` loops once. Then your own code loops over that data again. You still haven't explained what the problem is, just asked for what you assume the solution should be. Something used for *games and multimedia processing* which need sub-ms latencies to avoid jerky motion or sound distortion

Comment: You're polling every 15 seconds, so what latency are you worried about? One can guess you're cloning data, but why should that take so long? Besides, you already have timestamps. Why not process the data only up to a point, to avoid incomplete data in the last `tick` ? Whatever the problem is, others have encountered and solved it before.

Comment: Move the dictionary to the processing thread and queue updates to it?  Timeout your P-C queue/blockingCollection/whatever wait so that the processing will happen every 15s. During the processing, the pending updates will just queue up and get applied when the processing is complete.

Comment: A better design of the containers could make the problem go away. We wouldn't be talking about latency if each loop iteration didn't take a long time, which allows new values could get inserted to the `SOLD` and `BOUGHT` containers while the loop was still running. This can be eliminated if *only* the records up to a point are retrieved instead of every single record. In other words, if symbol values were batched based on time, something done by a BatchBlock in TPL Dataflow or [Buffer in Rx.NET](https://www.mariuszwojcik.com/rx-net-buffer-concurrency/)

Comment: Or the containers could be *swapped* with empty ones every 15s, using eg Interlocked.CompareExchange, allowing the worker thread to process them at its own pace. Or instead of a worker polling containers, a pub/sub pipeline could be created with an intermediate batching step. Which is what Rx.NET offers out of the box by the way

Comment: @SalmaG so once again, what is SOLD and BOUGHT?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos SOLD and BOUGHT collections are arrays of Dictionaries that contain timestamped executed prices + volumes for each Symbol I'm working on (thus the indexation) the scoring is done on the whole collection each time because the formula we've elaborated relies on timestamp, executed price and volume, so each time this thread works it attributes a new score value to the same transaction line in BOUGHT[index] or SOLD[index], I hope I made it clear enough

Comment: @SalmaG put all that *in the question itself*, including the *actual types*. If I hadn't already worked with *very* high volume algos I wouldn't understand what you ask. The solution has nothing to do with locks or preventing thread switching. To avoid skewed snapshots you need to *remove* the need for an expensive `ToList()` that retrieves ... mostly the same data it already retrieved the last time. How are the dictionaries fed? Why not use eg ConcurrentQueue or Channel instead to feed the data to the subscriber instead of polling? Batching the data into 15s batches would be very cheap

Comment: @SalmaG I could write an answer based on quite a lot of assumptions - a FIX connection producing events that get to be processed in 15s batches that contain - what? The data just in those 15s? Or all data in the day up to the 15s? The easy case, with just 15s of data is relatively easy a single worker task receives the FIX messages and fills a dictionary. At the 15s mark it emits the full dictionary to the next step in the pipeline and starts filling a new dictionary. No more polling or skew

Comment: @SalmaG or perhaps a different pipeline per symbol or group of symbols? Essentially this partitions the input stream by symbol, and process each symbol independently. If you process 100s of symbols, creating 100 pipelines may be too much.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a critical section, i.e. a [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement). used like

```
lock(myLockObject){
     // do uninteruptable work
}
```

where myLockObject is a object that is shared by all threads that use the resources. Any thread that uses the dictionaries will need to take this lock using the same object. You might be able to use a [readwritelock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=netcore-3.1) to reduce contention, but that would require more details about your specific use case. If you are using regular dictionaries you will need some kind of locking anyway since dictionaries are not threadsafe, this can be avoided by using [concurrentDictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1).

If you do not depend on the dictionary snapshot being taken at the same time you can simply use concurrentDictionaries and run your loop without locking, and deal with the consequences.

The idea of "uninteruptable" does not really exist in c#, it is the OS that controls all scheduling of threads. Processors have a feature to disable interrupts that have sort of that effect, but this is used for system level programming and not for regular client software.

Comment: Locking doesn't do what the OP asks, which isn't even related to the actual problem anyway.  The OP complains about the latency introduced between retrieving the stock data and processing it. Locking won't make slow cloning code run faster

Comment: @panagiotis kanavos locking will prevent the dictionaries from being changed while the snapshot is created, ensuring that all dictionaries reflect a single point in time. The question specifies "I want the snapshots of all dictionaries to be as close in time as possible", it does not mentions performance, nor any delay between snapshotting data and processing. And locking is about making the code correct, and correctness is almost always more important than performance.

Comment: `to be as close in time as possible` is latency, not correctness. Besides, there's only a single thread involved in `ThreadProc_Scoring`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are targeting a [multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) operating system (like Windows, Linux, Android, macOS, iOS, Solaris etc), the closest you can get to an un-interruptible section is to run this section on a thread configured with the maximum [priority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.priority):

```
var thread = new Thread(GetTheSnapshots);
thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
thread.Start();
```

You should not expect it to be consistently and deterministically un-interruptible though, since the operating system is not obligated to schedule the thread on a time-slice of infinite duration.